# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In my code, I use fop.jar to read pdf file but I get  error from log file:

```
EXCEPTION]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException
at GetPagePdf.<init>(GetPayStubPdf.java:36)
```

in my code line 36:

```
private FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
```

I research on website, they answer I miss avalonframework.jar but i don't know how to use jar file. Please help me to give some ideas.

Comment: It's possible that fob.jar also has dependencies that must be found in your classpath.

Comment: on classpath file, i see fop.jar added on it:

Comment: There are a lot more than just fop. See my answer below for details I've listed all the dependencies that FOP requires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Formatting Object project (fop.jar) has dependencies that must also be placed into your classpath. The class that is throwing the `NoClassDefFoundError` is part of the avalon-framework-api.jar and avalon-framework-impl.jar.

The dependencies as I know of them if you are using fop version 2.1

1. avalon-framework-api 4.3.1
2. avalon-framework-impl 4.3.1
3. batik-anim 1.8
4. batik-awt-util 1.8
5. batik-bridge 1.8
6. batik-css 1.8
7. batik-dom 1.8
8. batik-ext 1.8
9. batik-extension 1.8
10. batik-gvt 1.8
11. batik-parser 1.8
12. batik-script 1.8
13. batik-svg-dom 1.8
14. batik-svggen 1.8
15. batik-transcoder 1.8
16. batik-util 1.8
17. batik-xml 1.8
18. commons-io 2.5
19. commons-logging 1.0.4
20. xalan 2.7.0
21. xml-apis 1.0.b2
22. xml-apis-ext 1.3.04
23. xmlgraphics-commons 2.1

If you find all of these then put them into your classpath then you should be able to run FOP.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do it

Comment: Do you have list of dependencies if I use fop version 1.1 ?

Comment: Sorry no, I'm using the most recent release of FOP.

Comment: My issue is resolved. Once again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Download and add `avalonframework.jar` to your `classpath` same as you did for  `fop.jar`.

As **JRSofty** mentioned in his post, you should satisfy all the dependency libs for `fop.jar` to make your program work.

Comment: In my classpath, the avalonframework is added:
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/External_Lib/SP18_libs/fop.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/External_Lib/SP18_libs/avalon-framework.jar"/>

Comment: So, what happened?

Comment: You need more than those two jar files.